# Can someone help me understand what the problem here is and possible solutions?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I"m still new to JS and localStorage and I'm trying to understand it better. I am trying to be able to take 2 inputs from the user and when a button is clicked it displays those values (sort of like a todo list). I'm trying to implement localStorage and I'm able to save the key/value pair but I can't seem to display them properly. I'm able to click the button and display the values the first time I do it but the second click gives me a "Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 24 (line 1 column 25)" console message after.

Can someone help me understand what the problem is?
My goal is figure out how to display multiple items stored in a object.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="inputField">
        <input type="text" class="inputFieldTwo">
        <button id="btn">Click</button>

        <div class="sample">
            
        </div>

        
    </div>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
const userInput = document.querySelector(".inputField");
const userInputTwo = document.querySelector(".inputFieldTwo");
const button = document.querySelector("#btn");
const contain = document.querySelector('.sample');

let arr = [];


button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let thisObj = {
        user: `${userInput.value}`,
        num: `${userInputTwo.value}`
    }

    let strObj = JSON.stringify(thisObj);
 
    arr.push(strObj)

    localStorage.setItem("data", arr)

    let parseObj = JSON.parse(arr);

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let input = document.createElement("input");
        let inputTwo = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        inputTwo.type = "number";

        input.value = parseObj.user
        inputTwo.value = parseObj.num
 
        localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(arr));

        contain.appendChild(input);
        contain.appendChild(inputTwo);
        return
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Looks like the code doesn't like something about the JSON string you're inputting.  What does it look like?

Comment: hello, thanks for responding. What do you mean exactly by what does it look like? the console log error? or what I'm typing into the input field? or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant what you saved in the localstorage.  What does the JSON string look like?

Comment: There are few problems here. The first `localStorage.setItem` uses an array as a value, which is not supported by `setItem`. The value should be of string type. Then you do `let parseObj = JSON.parse(arr);` on arr which is not a string. This won't work. The second call to `localStorage.setItem` is done with the `JSON.stringify` result, which is a string and acceptable, but why are you executing it in the loop if you don't change `arr` in that loop?  What is the purpose of the code?

Answer (score 1):

I see `setItem` item twice but you never actually try to return the localStorage by using `getItem`. For setting the localStorage value I would do something like this:

```
// Save data as object
let thisObj = {
    user: userInput.value,
    num: userInputTwo.value
}

// Add to your global array
arr.push(thisObj);

// Stringify array and save data to localStorage
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Then for reading data you can do it like this:

```
// Read data from localStorage and parse JSON
let parseObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
```

Then inside of your loop you could access the entries as follows

```
let entry = parseObj[i];
input.value = entry.user
inputTwo.value = entry.num
```

I'd suggest to also initially get the data from localStorage before any click happened and adding the data to your global `arr`-Array. This way you will also have the saved data on page load (currently you would have to add a new entry to see the rest of the data)